# How to render a custom error message in active_model_serializers JSON API

Tags: active-model-serializers, rails-api

As AMS [docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/jsonapi/errors.md) say, we could use `ActiveModel::Serializer::ErrorSerializer` to generate JSON API errors response. It seems like it calls `errors` and suppose to have an ActiveModel object.
So the below code works and send the error response message but not the code (ite responds with `500` code), and it does not use `ErrorSerializer` either.

```
def user_not_authorized
  render jsonapi: errors_response, status: :unathorized
end

def errors_response
    {
      errors:
        [
          { message: 'You are not authorized to perform this action.' }
        ],
      title:  'Invalid Attribute'
    }
  end
```

Moreover, it displays in the console:

```
Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash
```

When trying to use `ErrorSerializer` as follows:

```
def user_not_authorized
    render jsonapi: errors_response, status: :unathorized, serializer: ActiveModel::Serializer::ErrorSerializer
end
```

raises the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `errors' for #<Hash:0x00007fcf12d84d78>)
```

There was an [issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1744) opened at AMS repo about that and sems like it is not implemented.
Any idea on what is right way to do that in Rails API app?

Comment: Hmm, just changing `render jsonapi: errors_response, status: :unathorized` to   `render jsonapi: errors_response, status: 401`, sent back the right status of `401` and it is what was needed.

Comment: Damned, it was a typo in `unathorized` which should be `unauthorized`, - so both worked for me :).